# Updating single field to include 4 columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update `Item.ItemLookupCode` to be a combination of

```
ItemClass.ItemLookupCode + 
MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder.Code(Dimension 1) + 
MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder.Code(Dimension 2) + 
MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder.Code(Dimension 3)
```

Which would return `Item.ItemLookupCode = F06555SND36LG`

Using the following tables below. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you:

`db.Item`:

```
   ID | ItemLookupCode
-----------------------
68883 | 4344110101
```

`db.ItemClassComponent`:

```
ID    |ItemClassID | ItemID | Detail1 | Detail2 | Detail3
----------------------------------------------------------    
68883 | 2566       | 68905  | Sand    | 36      | Long
```

`db.MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder`:

```
ID    | ItemClassID | Dimension | Attribute | Code
---------------------------------------------------    
19769 | 2566        | 2         | 36        | 36
19774 | 2566        | 3         | Long      | LG
47708 | 2566        | 1         | Sand      | Snd
 1200 |   88        | 1         | 32 Short  | 32S
 4272 |  366        | 3         | Long      | LNG
 3207 |  266        | 3         | Short     | SH
19767 | 2566        | 1         | Navy      | NVY
19768 | 2566        | 2         | 34        | 34
19772 | 2566        | 3         | Short     | SH
```

`db.ItemClass`:

```
ID   | ItemLookupCode
----------------------    
2566 | F06555
```

Comment: Are you using sql-server, or MySQL?   You have both tags.

Comment: @jpw This is a pre-set number and isn't based on any other fields.

Comment: In sql server, you do concatenation with the plus (+) sign.

Comment: @Revokez Ok, so what should the value be after the update?

Comment: @jpw           It should have the value "68905SND36LG"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want, if you want to test it you can just run the select query by itself to what value are returned. With SQL 2012 and later you can use`concat()`to merge values into a string, if you're on a lower version change to the line that's commented out now.

```
update Item
set ItemLookupCode = LookupCodes.ItemLookupCode
from Item i 
inner join 
(
  select 
    icc.id, 
    -- SQL 2012+
    ItemLookupCode = upper(concat(ic.ItemLookupCode, m1.code, m2.code, m3.code))
    -- pre SQL 2012 
    -- ItemLookupCode = upper(ic.ItemLookupCode + m1.code + m2.code + m3.code)  
  from ItemClassComponent icc
  inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m1 
    on icc.ItemClassID = m1.ItemClassID and m1.Dimension = 1
  inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m2 
    on icc.ItemClassID = m2.ItemClassID and m2.Dimension = 2
  inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m3 
    on icc.ItemClassID = m3.ItemClassID and m3.Dimension = 3
  inner join ItemClass ic 
    on icc.ItemClassID = ic.ID
) LookupCodes on LookupCodes.ID = i.ID
where i.ID = 68883;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/792a7/1)

Another version of the query that incorporates additional requirements put forward in comments:

```
select 
    icc.id, 
    -- SQL 2012+
    ItemLookupCode = upper(concat(ic.ItemLookupCode, m1.code, m2.code, m3.code))
    -- pre SQL 2012 
    -- ItemLookupCode = upper(ic.ItemLookupCode + m1.code + m2.code + m3.code)  
from ItemClassComponent icc
inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m1 
     on icc.ItemClassID = m1.ItemClassID 
    and icc.Detail1 = m1.Attribute 
    and m1.Dimension = 1
inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m2 
     on icc.ItemClassID = m2.ItemClassID 
    and icc.Detail2 = m2.Attribute
    and m2.Dimension = 2     
inner join MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder m3 
     on icc.ItemClassID = m3.ItemClassID 
    and icc.Detail3 = m3.Attribute 
    and m3.Dimension = 3
inner join ItemClass ic 
     on icc.ItemClassID = ic.ID
```

Comment: That's great thank you for taking the time to do that. However can you modify it so it is specifically for the Item.ID=68883

Comment: What Julian just said.

Comment: @jpw           Thanks! I really appreciate your help :) That's solved the problem.

Comment: @jpw           Thanks again for the help with this one. However I've ran into a small issue. Within the MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder there are other rows with the ItemClassId='2566'. However they have different attributes. Would it be possible to change this so that it also checks that ItemClassComponent.Detail1 = MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder.Attribute etc. for Detail1,2,3.

Comment: @Revokez I imagine it would be possible, but I don't quite understand the question. Do you mean that there are multiple rows for itemclassid 2566 with dimension 1, and you want to match on attribute instead (or also)? It might be enough to just add the `ItemClassComponent.Detail1 = MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder.Attribute` to the join conditions for each join.

Comment: @jpw           Yes, that's correct. I've updated the MatrixDisplayOrder table with the some additional rows which are causing the problem.

Comment: @Revokez I've updated my answer and added another version of the select part, I think this is what you want.

Comment: @Revokez Also, I just noticed that the example output in the question is different from what you describe - the result `68905SND36LG` seems to use the itemID from the ItemClassComponent table and not ItemClass.ItemLookupCode so maybe you want this: `ItemLookupCode = upper(concat(icc.ItemID, m1.code, m2.code, m3.code))`

Comment: @jpw           Thank you for the updated answer, that looks to solve the problem. The example answer that I provided was a typo on my part, thanks for pointing that out, I have amended this.

Comment: @jpw           That seems to have resolved the problem, thanks. I've ran into one last final issue however. On some, they do not have a ItemClassComponent.Detail3. It is just blank. For these the query is not working. Is it possible to modify it so that it works if the Detail3 is blank?

Comment: @Revokez You could try changing the join condition to `and (icc.Detail3 = m3.Attribute or icc.Detail3 is null)`but then you would get matches for the other row and get both F06555SND36LG
and F06555SND36SH. I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly which fields you want to have concatenated, but here it is with the code fields.  It will do the entire table as a set.

```
UPDATE item SET ItemLookupCode = Result
FROM Item INNER JOIN (
SELECT icc.id, CONCAT(ic.ItemLookupCode, M1.Code1, m2.Code2,m3.Code3) AS Result
FROM ItemClassComponent icc
LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemClass ic on icc.ItemClassID = ic.ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Code AS Code1 FROM MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder D1 WHERE D1.ItemClassID = icc.ItemClassID  AND D1.Dimension = 1 ) M1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Code AS Code2 FROM MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder D1 WHERE D1.ItemClassID = icc.ItemClassID  AND D1.Dimension = 2 ) M2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Code AS Code3 FROM MatrixAttributeDisplayOrder D1 WHERE D1.ItemClassID = icc.ItemClassID  AND D1.Dimension = 3 ) M3
) T1 ON item.ID = t1.ID
```